# Background image cover does not scale the image down

Tags: html, css, background-image

I've got a calendar div (that actually has height and width set to 100vh and 100vw to be fullscreen) containing a header and an actual calendar.

I use flex because I want the header to have a specific height, and the contained calendar to take all the vertical space it has left.

rbc-calendar is actually an external library I use [(React Big Calendar)](https://github.com/intljusticemission/react-big-calendar) which uses flex on its own to scale the rows. I've put the main div css in case it comes in relevant.

I want my calendar container to have a background image. So only for the calendar itself, not the header. I want this image to be scaled down until the height (width) fits the calendar's height (weight), keeping the image's aspect ratio and letting it overflow for the same amount on right/left (top/bottom).

`Background-image: cover` seems to be what I'm looking for, but for some reasons the image does not get scaled down at all.

```css
.calendar {
  height: 333px;
  width: 333px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.calendar-header {
    height: 40px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background: lightblue;
}

.calendar-container {
    flex: 1;
    background-size: cover;
    background: #000 url('https://www.chenhuijing.com/slides/29-constellation-2018/img/meme1.jpg') no-repeat center center;
}

.rbc-calendar {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
}
```

```html
<div class="calendar">
  <div class="calendar-header">
    <h1>Not working calendar</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="calendar-container">
    <div class="rbc-calendar">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: because you declared background AFTER background-size, so you override it ... do the opposite or include cover in the background

Comment: This is one of those moments when I feel like the dumbest human being the earth has never seen. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Answer in the question's comments by [Temani-afif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8620333/temani-afif) : setting background after `background-size` overrides the statement.